# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop (Using Rails with React )

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, graphql

When I try to iterate through my variable `badges` and display each badge, I get this error :

> > Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

```
    var badges = author.badges.map((badge, index) => <span className="author__badge">
                                                        <Icon key={"icon" + index} name={`icon-${badge}`} />
                                                       </span>;
                                  );
      return (

          <span className="author__name">{author.name}</span>

            { author.badge === "" ||
                badges
            }
            <span className="author__nickname">{author.nickname}</span>
          </div>
      );
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: Yes sorry I know. I already saw the related questions but still have the same error. So I wonder if it doesn't come to somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) :

> A good rule of thumb is that elements inside the map() call need keys.

You need to make use of `key={ }` and give it any unique value

**When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort**

So in your case one of the ways (You can amend it accordingly):

```
var badges = author.badges.map((badge, index) => 
              <span className="author__badge" key={index}>);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I forgot to add !

Answer (score 0):

Just move the key from Icon to the  tag including the two spans outside the array.

```
var badges = author.badges.map((badge, index) => <span className="author__badge">
                                                    <Icon key={author.name + "icon" + index} name={`icon-${badge}`} />
                                                   </span>;
                              );
  return (
      <div> // This was missing
      <span key={author.name} className="author__name">{author.name}</span>

        { author.badge === "" ||
            badges
        }
        <span key= {"nick" + author.name}className="author__nickname">{author.nickname}</span>
      </div>
  );
```

Or something similar. It this component is used in and array maybe a key will be needed for the div also.