# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check render method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, key, react-props, react-tsx

Hi so I am pretty new to programming and I got kinda stuck with a problem. I've built an interface with array of objects and with property 'id'. I used it (id: property) as my Unique key but it gives me an error.
Thats's the interface

```js
export interface IState {
  meetupsy: {
      id: number
  }[]
}
```

and that's a List component

```js
import classes from './MeetupList.module.css'
import { IState as Props } from '../../App'
import Card from '../ui/Card'

interface IProps {
    meetups: Props['meetupsy']
}

const MeetupList: React.FC<IProps> = ({meetups}) => {

    const renderList = ():JSX.Element[] => {
        return meetups.map((meetup) => {
            return <Card>
                <li key={meetup.id} className={classes.list}>
                    <div className={classes.image} />
                </li>
            </Card>
        })
    }

    return (
        <ul className={classes.render}>
            {renderList()}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default MeetupList;
```

I am really puzzled it says "Check the render method of `MeetupList`"

Comment: The key needs to be on the outermost element in your `map` callback. So the `Card`, not the `li`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop (Using Rails with React )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585944/each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-using-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question was answered multiple times.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Each+child+in+an+array+should+have+a+unique+%22key%22+prop.)

Each of the elements you are iterating through must have a `key` property that must be put in the outermost element and must be unique.

```
const renderList = (): JSX.Element[] =>
  meetups.map((meetup) => (
    <Card key={meetup.id}>
      ...
    </Card>
  ));
```